# Usage of enum - global and local

Tags: c++, enums, global, local

I just tried it to use globaly defined enum with same name as locally defined.

I had initiallized with same values except the start point.

```
enum Day {Sunday = 1 ,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday /*= 15 */,Saturday};

void enumUse() {
    enum Day {Sunday = 2 ,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday /*= 15 */,Saturday};
    Day today = Tuesday;
    cout<<Sunday<<endl;
    cout<<Monday<<endl;
    cout<<Tuesday<<endl;
    cout<<Wednesday<<endl;
    cout<<Thursday<<endl;
    cout<<Friday<<endl;
    cout<<Saturday<<endl;
    cout<<"Today: "<<today;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This code snippet gives the output of local enum.

If comment it out, it gives output related to global one.

How could I use global enum without commenting local enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **scope resolution operator**, because the global `Day` is defined in global scope

```
//'Day' from global scope
::Day today = ::Tuesday; //'Tuesday' also needs it because it would take the local one,
                         //which can't be assigned to the global 'Day' (they're different
                         //enums after all)
```